# Email validation is not working correctly - don't know why it's not running properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating this function to change the styles of my input when an invalid input is typed in. Everything works fine except the email validation. (I want the border to change to green when everything is working, and to red when it's not. All of my console logs are coming out exactly as I want them to, so I believe the regex statement is correct... it's just not changing the border like it's supposed to.

Any idea why?

```
onInputBlur = (event) => {
   console.log('onblur')
    let inputInfo = event.target
    let inputVal = event.target.value,
        { styles } = this.props,
        fontSize = styles.placeholder.fontSize || 10,
        top = styles.placeholder.top || 4
    let emailRegex = new RegExp(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i);
       console.log(inputInfo.id.toString())
       console.log(emailRegex.test(inputVal))




if(inputVal){
  //zipcode
           if(inputInfo.id.toString() == 'zip' && inputVal.split('').length < 4){
               console.log('ziphit')
                return this.setState(state =>({
                  inputCSS:{
                   ...state.inputCSS,
                   border: '1px solid red'
                 }
              }))
          } else if (inputInfo.id.toString() == 'zip' && inputVal.split('').length >= 4){
                return this.setState(state => ({
                  inputCSS: {
                    ...state.inputCSS,
                    border: '1px solid green'
                  }
                }))
              }
  //phone
          if(inputInfo.id.toString() == 'phone' && inputVal.split('').length < 10){
            return this.setState(state =>({
              inputCSS: {
                ...state.inputCSS,
                border: '1px solid red'
              }
            }))
          } else {
            return this.setState(state => ({
              inputCSS: {
                ...state.inputCSS,
                border: '1px solid green'
              }
            }))
          }
  //email
          if(inputInfo.id.toString() == 'email' && !emailRegex.test(inputVal)){
            console.log('email hit - invalid input')
            return this.setState(state => ({
              inputCSS: {
                ...state.inputCSS,
                border: '1px solid red'
              }
            }))
          } else {
            console.log('email hit - valid email')
            return this.setState(state => ({
              inputCSS: {
                ...state.inputCSS,
                border: '1px solid green'
              }
            }))
          }

    return this.setState(state =>({
      inputCSS: {
        ...state.inputCSS,
        border: '1px solid green'
     }
   }))
 }  else {
      return this.setState(state=> ({
        inputCSS: {
          ...state.inputCSS,
          border: '1px solid red'
        }
    }))
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a LOT of code to look through and 'guess' what is going wrong. Do you have a working example for us? Or a jsfiddle maybe? On these types of issues I always ask a few questions first; 1 ) Does the element get rendered with the html or do you render it through javascript? 2 ) does the element even have a border and is it not within a wrapper containing an `overflow:hidden`? - is the console.log('email hit') coming through?

Comment: I don't have a JSFiddle of it, but it's being rendered via React jsx. It does have a visible border that is black upon page load. If you click on it and leave it blank, the border will successfully turn red, but if you type any string value at all, it will turn green. The console logs that say 'email hit - invalid input' and 'email hit - valid input' are not firing so they are somehow not getting activated, even though the console says inputInfo.id is successfully returning 'email' and the email.Regex.text(inputVal) is successfully returning the correct boolean value.

Comment: Leads me to believe that it doesn't have to do with overflow:hidden - all the other input values are successsfully changing their styles as desired. Fairly certain it just has to do with the logic here.

Comment: then I assume the input is at least being found (as an element) properly. That means we can look at your code for errors. If what you say is true, though, it should be quite simple; If the `console.log('email hit')` isn't firing, it's not getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking with if/else @ phone. Try console.logging in the phone case's `else` (which is ran before email) and I'm assuming it will fire the `console.log();` you put there now.

You see, the statement `if(inputInfo.id.toString() == 'phone' && inputVal.split('').length < 10)` will ALWAYS return to `else` if the field you're typing in is not `phone`.

So, you never get past the phone's `else` statement. Email is underneath it, but the function returns before it ever gets there. The email check will never be executed.

It should be like your first function, like this;

```
 if(inputInfo.id.toString() == 'phone' && inputVal.split('').length < 10){
            return this.setState(state =>({
              inputCSS: {
                ...state.inputCSS,
                border: '1px solid red'
              }
            }))
          } else if(inputInfo.id.toString() == 'phone') {
            return this.setState(state => ({
              inputCSS: {
                ...state.inputCSS,
                border: '1px solid green'
              }
            }))
          }
```

-- Make sure you do this for all of these cases.

By the way, in general, switch-cases are used in these types of scenarios.
A switch case doesn't need the else-if's. It actually breaks on the case it should be on, preventing issues like the one you are facing right now.
 Like so;

```
var fieldType = inputInfo.id.toString();
switch (fieldType) {
  case "phone":
    if (inputVal.split('').length) {
      //return on true
    } else {
      //return on false;
    }
    break;
}
```

**It's even better practice to not have so many returns in your code, like so;**

```
var fieldType = inputInfo.id.toString();
var returnValue = {};
switch (fieldType) {
  case "phone":
    if (inputVal.split('').length) {
      returnValue.state = "my stuff";
    } else {
      returnValue.state = "my stuff";
    }
    break;
  case "email":
    if (inputVal.split('').length) {
      returnValue.state = "my stuff";
    } else {
      returnValue.state = "my stuff";
    }
    break;
}
return this.setState(returnValue);
```

Sorry for not using ES6. I don't know any ES6 syntax yet =)

Comment: You're super awesome, Babydead! Rock on. I will definitely attempt to implement this,

Comment: @ScaryBelles sure thing, boss! And thank you very much =) Please do not forget to mark my answer as 'the answer' for future question-visitors to know that this question was indeed resolved.

Comment: Ok I'm dumb. I am struggling to find where I click to make mark yours as the answer. Any hints?